# sql data fetch bug

Tags: php, sql

I have two pages . In the first page if user will click on button then he will get relavant data with id column

```
<form action='edit.php?id=$id' method='post' name='edit_btn'> 
<button type='submit' class='w3-btn w3-red w3-round-xlarge'>Proceed </button> 
</form>   

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","student_result_info_db");if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }else{ 
          if(isset($_GET['edit_btn'])){
              echo "<div class='w3-container w3-red'> <h1>>Error Found!</h1> <h4>OK You Did Hit The EDIT Button</h4> </div> <br/>";
          }else{  
             $get_selected_id = $_GET['id'];
             echo $get_selected_id;

             $res = "SELECT * FROM school_result";


                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                     echo "$row[id]. $row[first_name] <br/>";
                     echo "$row[id]. $row[last_name] <br/>";
                 } 
          }
    }
```

It'showing following error

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() in**

Comment: Are you using PHP 7? `mysql_fetch_array` was removed in PHP 7 and deprecated in PHP 5.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 yes, I using php 7

Comment: You are using `mysqli` to connect but try to use `mysql` to fetch the data, you can't mix match like that.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 So what's the solution ?

Comment: @GourabMazumder I have posted an answer below.

Comment: @Epodax I using php 7 . Please give me correct code for this bug

Comment: @GourabMazumder It's all ready been provided, but just a FYI, it's **not** a bug, your code is wrong. - And also, you need to execute your query, do please find a tutorial on php / mysql and learn it, your code is showing a lack of understanding.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Now I using `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $res))){ ` It's working but it's fetchng all data from database but i I need fetch which id is maching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead, along with `mysqli_query` to get a `mysqli_result` object:

```
$qresult = mysqli_query($con, $res);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qresult)){
```

You need to use this for 2 reasons:

1. You opened your database using `mysqli_connect`, so you need to use the `mysqli` functions.
2. `mysql` functions were removed in PHP 7.

Comment: it's hsowing error **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in**

Comment: @GourabMazumder Sorry: I'll change my answer.

Comment: @GourabMazumder I've changed my answer to use `mysqli_query`.

Comment: It's fetching but here is a problem . In the db many rows of data was inserted and now **I need fetch only which row that  column `ïd` is matching** and it also showing a error **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in**

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli function instead of mysql like

```
mysqli_query($con, $res);
```

Comment: it's show error **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in**

Comment: have you used mysqli_query function

Comment: It's fetching but here is a problem . In the db many rows of data was inserted and now **I need fetch only which row that  column `ïd` is matching** and it also showing a error **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in**